# Find out if apk is published as beta or as stable at runtime

Tags: java, android, admob

I have uploaded an android app in the Google Play Developer Console in the (public) beta phase. Now I want to publish the next version as "stable" with (admob) ads. But I don't want the beta users to see those ads. So I need a way to figure out if the app is beta or stable at runtime.

Thank you for any suggestions and answers!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you need to set different version for both Beta And stable version then you can check current version of the app and make condition on the basis of the version only .

Comment: I want to upload one apk in alpha. Then push it to beta and stable. If there are no bugs, I don't want to change the apk file